# Any examples of Sinatra+Warden with 'confirmation' and 'forgot password' mail support?

Tags: sinatra, warden

Are there examples of how to use Sinatra and Warden with 'confirmation' and 'forgot password' mail support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my reading of the Warden documentation, 'confirmation' and 'forgot password' are largely outside the scope of Warden.  Here is how to approach implementing confirmation as an example.

1. Add `confirm` and `confirmed?` methods to your `User` class.
2. Add a `:unconfirmed` scope to warden.  This will be used to allow access to your confirmation page when logged in, but not confirmed.
3. In your Warden `authenticate!` method, check both the `User`s authentication as well as the `confirmed?` method.
4. Add a system for sending confirmation emails on new messages.